# Is 0xFFFF a valid Unicode character?

Tags: c++, unicode

I just wonder whether 0xFFFF is a valid Unicode character.

When I using the following code:

```
CStringW strTempW;
CString strTemp1;
INT_PTR nLen;

strTempW.Format(L"%c", 0xFFFF);
nLen = strTempW.GetLength();

strTemp1 += strTempW;
nLen = strTemp1.GetLength();
```

After executing the first codeline `strTempW.Format(L”%c”, 0xFFFF)`, I will get `strTempW` of length 1, but cannot see it first character in Visual Studio watch window.

After executing the codeline `strTemp1 += strTempW`, I will get `strTemp1` of length 0.

That is confusing to me. Is 0xFFFF taken as a valid Unicode code point or not?

Comment: Are you referring to a code point or to a character encoding?

Answer (score 13):

Go to the Unicode web site [unicode.org/charts](http://unicode.org/charts) and enter FFFF in the box.  It will give you a PDF to download (`UFFF0.pdf` for this character code; different files for different codes).

You'll find that U+FFFF is not a valid Unicode character:

> FFFF `<`not a character`>`
>
> - The value FFFF is guaranteed not to be a Unicode character at all

Comment: Moreover, *all* the last two bytes in each plane are excluded.

Comment: Thanks, @KerrekSB. That doesn't surprise me, but I'd not validated it. I knew that U+10FFFF, the largest value in Unicode, is not a character, but I didn't want to generalize without investigating (and I was too lazy to investigate at the moment).

Answer (score 4):

As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482683/can-a-valid-unicode-string-contain-ffff-is-java-characteriterator-broken) great answer it is not, it is a reserved non character.