# Are there any common C environments where EOF != -1 or WEOF != -1

Tags: c, macros, language-lawyer, eof

The C Standard defines `EOF` and `WEOF` with the following language:

> **7.21.1 Input/output<stdio.h> - Introduction**
>
> The header `<stdio.h>` defines several macros, and declares three types and many functions for performing input and output.
>
> ...
>
> **`EOF`**
>
> which expands to an integer constant expression, with type int and a negative value, that is returned by several functions to indicate end-of-file, that is, no more input from a stream;
>
> ...

> **7.21.1 Extended multibyte and wide character utilities <wchar.h> - Introduction:**
>
> The header `<wchar.h>` defines four macros, and declares four data types, one tag, and many functions.
>
> ...
>
> **`wint_t`**
>
> which is an integer type unchanged by default argument promotions that can hold any value corresponding to members of the extended character set, as well as at least one value that does not correspond to any member of the extended character set
>
> **`WEOF`**
>
> which expands to a constant expression of type wint_t whose value does not correspond to any member of the extended character set.(328) It is accepted (and returned) by several functions in this subclause to indicate end-of-file, that is, no more input from a stream. It is also used as a wide character value that does not correspond to any member of the extended character set.
>
> ---
>
> 328. The value of the macro WEOF may differ from that of EOF and need not be negative.

`EOF` is a negative value and it is the only negative value that `getc()` can return.  I have seen it commonly defined as `(-1)`, and similarly `WEOF` defined as `((wint_t)-1)`.

Are there any common C environments where either of these macros are defined to something different?

What is the rationale for the Standard Committee to leave open the possibility of different values and especially a non-negative value for `WEOF`?

Comment: It also very much depends on what `wint_t` is defined as. If it is, for example, an `unsigned short` and `sizeof(int) > sizeof(unsigned short)`, then `EOF != WEOF` (it has to do with sign extension, or rather the lack thereof).

Comment: Why bother? Using the macros instead of magic numbers is good practice and makes the code clearer anyway. Re. `wint`: IIRC, Windows has 16 bit `wchar_t` which requires all 16 bits to represent characters. Allowing non-negative values for `WEOF` would allow to reserve a single code for the marker instead half of the available codespace.

Comment: Hypothetically, an implementation might have some legitimate use for `-1` as a character code, so might want to pick a different value for `EOF`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What is the rationale for the Standard Committee to leave open the possibility of different values and especially a non-negative value for `WEOF`?*

The type int is always signed, a negative value is always included in the range, thus the `EOF` macro can be defined by the standard as -1.

However the type `wint_t` may be signed or unsigned<sup>1</sup>, so the macro `WEOF` cannot be defined by the standard as a specific value. The implementation must choose it, since the implementation defines the type `wint_t` and its signess, it must also choose a value for `WEOF`.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 7.20.3 Limits of other integer types 5)
If `wint_t` (see 7.29) is defined as a signed integer type, the value of `WINT_MIN` shall be no greater than −32767 and the value of `WINT_MAX` shall be no less than 32767; otherwise, `wint_t` is defined as an unsigned integer type, and the value of `WINT_MIN` shall be 0 and the value of `WINT_MAX` shall be no less than 65535.

Comment: I would love to read constructive comments along with downvotes on a correct answer.

Comment: I did not downvote, but it is IMHO quite misleading to define `wint_t` as an **unsigned** type: the name says otherwise. I thought the Rationale for `wint_t` was to have a possibly larger type to handle all values of `wchar_t` and some special value indicating the end of file. In the end, The whole wide char support is a mess: `wchar_t` can be signed, but `L'a'` is unsigned, `char16_t` and `char32_t` are unsigned, but `char` may signed and it is possible that `'\xFF' == EOF`... To top this bazaar of confusion, `WEOF` can be unsigned, different from `EOF`.

Comment: @chqrlie How is it my fault what the standard defines?

Comment: I am not saying it is your fault, as a matter of fact, I upvoted your answer, I am just underlining the potential inconsistencies the Committee saw it fit to engrave into the Standard to reflect then current usage (I suppose).  Consistency would demand that both `char` and `wchar_t`  be unsigned and `wint_t` be signed with a larger range, and both `EOF` and `WEOF` could be `(-1)` and `(wint_t)(-1)`.

Answer (score 3):

The value of -1 for `EOF` allows for simple efficient implementation of `ctype` macros (for the common case of small `char`, say 8 bits or so). A typical implementation may look like this:

```
unsigned __ctypes[257] = { 0 /* for EOF */, ... };

#define isalpha(c) (__ctypes[(c)+1] & _ALPHA_BITS)
```

There is no particular benefit in defining EOF as any other integer, so  -1 is likely to be used in any sensible implementation with small `char` type.

For large `wchar_t`, the table would be too large, so wctype functions are likely to be implemented differently. Hence less incentive to give WEOF any particular value, including -1.

Comment: The problem with this implementation is the lack of support for signed chars. Although it is incorrect to invoke `isalpha` with a `char` argument if this `char` can be negative, it is a **very** common mistake.  glibc's implementation uses an array of 384 entries to handle both signed and unsigned char values. On such an implementation, it would make sense to define `EOF` as `(-129)`.  Similarly, defining `WEOF` as `((wint_t)(-1))` avoids unnecessary harshness on programmers that mistakenly use `((c  = getc(f)) != EOF)` on wide streams.

Answer (score 1):

In Xinu OS [`EOF` is defined as `-2`](https://github.com/xinu-os/xinu/blob/master/include/stddef.h). See [Actual implementation of EOF different from -1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48583103/995714)

OTOH **`wint_t` can be an unsigned type**, so there are many actual implementations where `WEOF != -1`. For example in MSVC `wint_t` is `unsigned short` and `WEOF` is `(wint_t)(0xFFFF)`. Technically [U+FFFF isn't a valid Unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20735405/995714) so it can be used for `WEOF`, just like `-1` being used for `EOF` in implementations where `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)`. See also

- [Is wint_t always at least as large as wchar_t? And how can unsigned short satisfy reqirements of wint_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60940943/995714)
- [Can sizeof(int) ever be 1 on a hosted implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3860943/995714)
- [Can an implementation that has sizeof (int) == 1 "fully conform"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30836207/995714)