# Is wint_t always at least as large as wchar_t? And how can unsigned short satisfy reqirements of wint_t?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, eof, wchar-t

It seems everyone assumes `wint_t` is at least as large as `wchar_t`. However C standard allows `wchar_t` range to have value that do not directly correspond to any character in extended character set:

> The values `WCHAR_MIN` and `WCHAR_MAX` do not necessarily correspond to members of the extended character set.

and:

> `wchar_t` , which is an integer type whose range of values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales; the null character shall have the code value zero.

and `wint_t` is required to be able to hold only values for members of extended character set and at least one additional value for `WEOF`:

> `wint_t` , which is an integer type unchanged by default argument promotions that can hold any value corresponding to members of the extended character set, as well as at least one value that does not correspond to any member of the extended character set (see `WEOF` below);

The requirement of `wint_t` being unchanged by default argument promotions also does not imply `wint_t` is larger than `wchar_t`, as `wchar_t` may also be large enough to be unchanged by default argument promotions.

So in some imaginary implementation, `wchar_t` might be defined large enough to hold many unnecessary values that are not in extended character set and also to bypass default argument promotions. This implementation then may choose to not to include those values in `wint_t`. This allows `wchar_t` to be larger than `wint_t`.

According to standard size of `wchar_t` must be at least 1 byte and `wint_t` at least 2 byte. (assuming 8-bit bytes)

Also in Microsoft Visual Studio `wint_t` is `typedef`ed to `unsigned short`. How this satisfies requirement of being unchanged by default argument promotions? I thought C allows 2-byte `wint_t` because `int` may be 2 byte in some implementation.

Comment: This [note](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note327) seems relevant.

Comment: @KamilCuk, wchar_t and wint_t may be same integer type but that does not mean they have to be. though in usual implementation which use UTF encodings they are. my concern is about c in general specially unusual implementations.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Extended-Char-Intro.html `in the GNU C Library wchar_t is always 32 bits wide`

Comment: gcc uses UTF-32 so wchar_t is 4 bytes.

Comment: In the GNU C library, `wchar_t` is a `typedef int` and `wint_t` is a `typedef unsigned int`.

Comment: @Aplet123 , so they are different types in GNU. GNU's unsigned int will remain unchanged by default argument promotions however Visual studio's unsigned short does not ! i wonder then is Visual studio violates c standard ?

Comment: `wint_t` cannot be a typedef for `unsigned short` in Standard C , if that is narrower than `int`

Comment: MS has never attempted to conform to any C standard beyond C90 though

Comment: This question seems to answer itself

Comment: @M.M thanks. what about first part do wchar_t can be larger than wint_t ?

Comment: well you quoted the requirements yourself, there is nothing specifying one must be larger than the other

Comment: @M.M actually yes, because 0xFFFF is not a valid Unicode code point so it's outside the extended character set and can be used for WEOF

Comment: @KamilCuk `in the GNU C Library wchar_t is always 32 bits wide` that's not true. If you set [`-fwide-exec-charset=UTF-16`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) then wchar_t will be a 2-byte type in GCC

Comment: @phuciv `-fwide-exec-charset` doesn't change the size of `wchar_t`. It changes the representation, not size of type. [aaaand godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/hca585)

Answer (score 1):

`wint_t` to `wchar_t` is the same as what `int` to `char`, therefore **an implementation where `sizeof(wchar_t) == sizeof(wint_t)` is completely legal**, just as [implementations where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char)` are allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3860943/995714). In fact for the `char` case it's even worse because you can't return a different type for `getc`, `fgetc`... whereas for `wint_t` you can simply typedef it as a wider type if necessary. You can also see that the standard even explicitly permits it

> Footnote 327) `wchar_t` and `wint_t` can be the same integer type.
>
> http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.29.1

The standard also said that *"The values WCHAR_MIN and WCHAR_MAX do not necessarily correspond to members of the extended character set*" and there's nothing wrong with that. The extended character set range can be smaller than `wchar_t` range because the same happens in `char`. For example if the basic character set is ASCII then it uses only half of the available range (or much less if `CHAR_BIT > 8`). `wint_t` is

> ... an integer type unchanged by default argument promotions that can hold any value corresponding to members of the extended character set, as well as at least one value that does not correspond to any member of the extended character set (see WEOF below);
>
> http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.3.1.3

so presumably its size may be even smaller than `wchar_t` if the extended character set is much smaller than the `wchar_t` set. Since [0xFFFF is guaranteed not to be a Unicode character at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20735405/995714), using it for `WEOF` is completely valid, although it's a little bit weird IMHO and I don't know why MS did that

If `sizeof(wchar_t) == sizeof(wint_t)` or `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char)` then there are also values that `char` and `wchar_t` can represent but `int` and `wint_t` can't in case `char`/`wchar_t`  is unsigned. In that case the conversion between them is implementation defined. That won't be any issues if you're working on text files although it'll cause problems if you're reading binary files. Anyway in that case for portability you need to explicitly test for EOF and error yourself

```
int c;
while((c = /* fgetwc(in) */ fgetc(in)) != EOF || (!feof(in) && !ferror(in)))
    fputc(c, out);
```

This is the same as [what TI suggested](https://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/C89_Support_in_TI_Compilers#Misunderstandings_about_TI_C)

> On targets where `sizeof(char)==sizeof(int)` (C2700, C2800, C5400, C5500), you still can't reliably use the return value of **`getc()`** to check for end of file, because 0xffff will be mistaken for the end of file. Use `feof()` instead.

[CMU](https://sei.cmu.edu/)'s [FIO34-C. Distinguish between characters read from a file and `EOF` or `WEOF`](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO34-C.+Distinguish+between+characters+read+from+a+file+and+EOF+or+WEOF) also said that

> Because `EOF` is negative, it should not match any unsigned character value. However, this is only true for [implementations](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/BB.+Definitions#BB.Definitions-implementation) where the `int` type is wider than `char`. On an implementation where `int` and `char` have the same width, a character-reading function can read and return a valid character that has the same bit-pattern as `EOF`. This could occur, for example, if an attacker inserted a value that looked like EOF into the file or data stream to alter the behavior of the program.
>
> The C Standard requires only that the int type be able to represent a maximum value of +32767 and that a char type be no larger than an int. Although uncommon, this situation can result in the integer constant expression EOF being indistinguishable from a valid character; that is, `(int)(unsigned char)65535 == -1`. Consequently, failing to use `feof()` and `ferror()` to detect end-of-file and file errors can result in incorrectly identifying the EOF character on rare implementations where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char)`.
>
> This problem is much more common when reading wide characters. The `fgetwc(`), `getwc()`, and `getwchar()` functions return a value of type `wint_t`. This value can represent the next wide character read, or it can represent `WEOF`, which indicates end-of-file for wide character streams. On most implementations, the `wchar_t` type has the same width as `wint_t`, and these functions can return a character indistinguishable from `WEOF`.
>
> In the UTF-16 character set, 0xFFFF is guaranteed not to be a character, which allows `WEOF` to be represented as the value -1. Similarly, all UTF-32 characters are positive when viewed as a signed 32-bit integer. All widely used character sets are designed with at least one value that does not represent a character. Consequently, it would require a custom character set designed without consideration of the C programming language for this problem to occur with wide characters or with ordinary characters that are as wide as `int`.

See also

- [*Might* an unsigned char be equal to EOF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29975874/995714)
- [Can `sizeof(int)` ever be 1 on a hosted implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3860943/995714)
- [Can an implementation that has `sizeof (int) == 1` “fully conform”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30836207/995714)
- [ctype.h and sizeof(int) == sizeof(char)](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.std.c/c/qC3Vs0BHwNU/m/YTuoBJBwKU4J?pli=1)