# swprintf fails with \xffff unicode characters

Tags: c, wchar-t

The following lines of code running with Visual Studio 2013:

```
wchar_t test[] = L"\xffff";
wchar_t buf[100];    
int ret = swprintf(&buf[0], 100, L"%ls", &test[0]);
```

It compiles successfully, but swprintf fails to output this character (res is -1). It's ok with any other character except **\xffff**. This character can be in any position of the string, and swprintf still fails. What's the problem?

Comment: You will need to fix the error.

Comment: Whenever you're asking about an error message, you need to include the exact text of the error message in your question.

Comment: It's not a valid Unicode string if it contains the code point U+FFFF. See [Can a valid Unicode string contain FFFF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482683/can-a-valid-unicode-string-contain-ffff-is-java-characteriterator-broken).

Comment: Is the output being save to a file such that you hex-dump it and know that the function failed/succeeded to output?  Or are you looking at a screen with textual output - in this case how do you know `'\xffff'` must print something that is visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSVC/MSVCRT has 16-bit `wchar_t` and thus uses `0xffff` as the value of `WEOF`, thereby precluding it from being a valid character and necessitating that it cause an error when used like this. This does not really preclude use of a Unicode *character*, since `U+FFFF` is a *non-character* in Unicode, but it's still rather undesirable behavior since UTFs are supposed to handle all *Unicode scalar values*, not just characters.

The only "fix" is to use a proper implementation with 32-bit `wchar_t` (I think cygwin should work on windows but I'm not sure; otherwise, any unix-like system).