# Storing a List of String Array in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

If I want to simply store an array of Strings in Realm, am I forced to wrap it in an custom class that extends `Object`?

Example:

```
class ExampleObject : Object {
   var stringArray : List<String> 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not since Realm-Cocoa 3.0.0.

> Loosen RLMArray and RLMResults's generic constraint from RLMObject to NSObject. This may result in having to add some casts to disambiguate types.

and

> **List can now contain values of types Bool, Int, Int8, Int16, Int32, Int64, Float, Double, String, Data, and Date (and optional versions of all of these)** in addition to Object subclasses.
>
> ***Querying Lists containing values other than Object subclasses is not yet implemented.***

So following should *just work*:

```
class Student : Object {
    let stringArray = List<String>()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Realm does not support the native types. Take a look at this post for a demonstration of how to do it:
[Storing an array of strings using Realm's RLMArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724595/storing-an-array-of-strings-using-realms-rlmarray/31730894#31730894)