# Checking the validity of a string in elixir

Tags: elixir

Why is the following not a valid binary string ?

```
String.valid?(<<239, 191, 191>>)
false
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bytes `239, 191, 191` in UTF-8 decodes to the Unicode Codepoint `U+FFFF`:

```
iex(1)> <<x::utf8>> = <<239, 191, 191>>
<<239, 191, 191>>
iex(2)> x
65535
iex(3)> x == 0xFFFF
true
```

which is a [Unicode Non-Character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3482683/320615) and [`String.valid?/1` has a list of all such characters](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/825e3dddf1679301f5943e57ce5000ed956fe138/lib/elixir/lib/string.ex#L1255-L1259) and returns `false` when it encounters any of those.

---

I couldn't find any function in Elixir that only checks for UTF-8 validity and skips non-character checks, but it's trivial to write one:

```
defmodule A do
  def valid_utf8?(<<_::utf8, rest::binary>>), do: valid_utf8?(rest)
  def valid_utf8?(<<>>), do: true
  def valid_utf8?(_), do: false
end

for binary <- [<<0>>, <<239, 191, 191>>, <<128>>] do
  IO.inspect {binary, String.valid?(binary), A.valid_utf8?(binary)}
end
```

Output:

```
{<<0>>, true, true}
{<<239, 191, 191>>, false, true}
{<<128>>, false, false}
```